# Syntax for using a saved jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

I would like to use a saved selector and drill down further with it. In this case I would like to access the link tag contained in the element with the id

**html**

```
<div id='selectedElement'>
   <a href="#">some link</a>
</div>


var $selector = $('#selectedElement');
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $selector = $('#selectedElement');

// a will contain a reference to all <a> elements that are a descendent of the
// the element with id "selectedElement"
var a = $selector.find('a');
```

since `$selector` has been assigned a jQuery object which contains references to elements in the DOM that match the selector `#selectedElement`, you can use the `$selector` variable to drill down further.

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
<div id='selectedElement'>
   <a href="#">some link</a>
</div>

var $selector = $('#selectedElement'),
    $anchor = $selector.find('a');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily use the same way:

```
var selector = $('#selectedElement');

alert( selector.find("a").attr("href") );
```

Comment: there isn't one that works in all browsers without additional addons/plugins.